# Why cant I push inside an array and use it in a function argument in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why are b and c are not identical in the below code?
What is the order of statement execution in line number 2?

```
var a = [1,2];
var b = new Array(a.push(1)); //[undefined, undefined, undefined]
var c = new Array(a);         // [[1, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: You could write `new Array((a.push(1), a))`, but that's not necessarily easier to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.push()` function returns the new length of the array, not the array itself. Thus, `b` is initialized to a 3-element empty array because `.push()` returns 3 (after adding the `1` to the end of the array `a`).

Comment: Personally I think it would have been more useful for `.push()` to have returned the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can also clone the array using the `slice` function as an alternative to constructors. And use this way if you want `a` to remain unchanged.

```
var a = [1,2];
var b = a.slice(); 
b.push(1);            // [[1, 2, 1]]
var c = b.slice();    // [[1, 2, 1]]
```